# How well do analyst ratings predict stock perfromance?

Tags: r, prediction, rating, accuracy

Consider a huge dataset of which the following is a characteristic sample:

```
stock.id date analyst1 analyst2 analyst3 return
       1 Jan         2       -2        1     10
       2 Feb        -1        2        0    -10
       3 Mar         0        2        0      3
       4 Apr         0        0        0      2
       5 May         1        0        2     -1
       6 Jun         1        0        2     -3
     ...
```

The "analyst" columns are ratings issued by individual stock analysts and the "return" column is the subsequent return on rated stock.  Here rating 2 means a strong buy and -2 means a strong sell.

I am looking for a statistical test or techniques that can tell me how well the analysts performed.  Ideally, I want to come up with scores to indicate which analysts have rated stocks correctly.

Comment: Welcome to CV, @AjayShankarBidyarthy. [Your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23495597/1217536) was too broad on SO; unfortunately, it isn't any less broad here.

Comment: Welcome to our site! Could you clarify the meanings of some of your variables? (1) Does `stock.id` identify different securities or is it just a record number? (2) Are the values of `return` measured in a consistent fashion, such as the return during the month immediately following each rating, or do the returns perhaps cover different amounts of time?